# How to pass a whole request String as Json in Android

Tags: android, json, json-rpc

I have to send this Json:

```
{"method":"startSession", "params":["email" "email@email.it", "password" "1234", "stayLogged" "1", "idClient" "IPHONE"], "id":1}
```

the problem is that:
I don't know how to send a json with **Exactly this form** because of the params' value array,
I must send the array as value of the key params, but if I try to use:

```
jsonObject.put("params", paramemsArr);
```

to put a String array, the *put* doesn't work correctly and the Json assume a wrong form

If I try to put the params in a Json array and add the json array in analogue way the json assume the wrong form

```
{"method":"startSession", "params":[{"email" "email@email.it", "password" "1234", "stayLogged" "1", "idClient" "IPHONE"}], "id":1}
```

How could I send a Json with exactly this form

```
{"method":"startSession", "params":["", "email@email.it", "password", "stayLogged", "idClient"], "id":1}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

define paramemsArr as JSONArray instead of a String array,
read more about JSONArray at http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html

Comment: I have tried to sent Json array but get a 500 error from server... my output json sent on println is {"id":1,"method":"startSession","params":["","email@email.it","password","stayLogged","idClient"]} that seems the same accepted by server, but dosn't work

Comment: did you get the output you want with using JSONArray ? maybe the problem is with the server

Comment: yes but the server doesn't recognize it as a json rpc call, with ios the same json is accepted and works fine

Comment: you understand that if it works with the same JSON with ios the problem is elsewhere ?

anyway, with JSONObject abd JSONArray you build a valid JSON string, please mark the answer as accepted